# This warning is not being suppressed by warnings=FALSE

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

MWE `test.Rmd` file:

````
---
title: ""
author: "Alex"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo = FALSE, warnings=FALSE}
a <- max()
```
The value of $a$ in the first code chunk is `r a`.


```{r include=FALSE}
a <- max()
```
The value of $a$ in the second code chunk is `r a`.
````

Produces:

[image: warnings not suppressed]

The first warning is not being suppressed but the second is by `include=FALSE`. However, `warnings=FALSE` has worked to suppress other warnings like package namespace clashes.

The packages I have are:

```
knitr_1.12.3
rmarkdown_0.9.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `warning=FALSE`, not `warnings=FALSE`.  It's too bad that there's not an "unrecognized chunk option" (meta-)warning here, but software can only do so much ...  (I'm surprised that `warnings=FALSE` has worked for you in the past - maybe this is just a one-time typo?)

Comment: StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1) (although I appreciate the "urgh" in this case); if this answer answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.